# Ускорить gradle build, Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, gradle, kotlin

У меня вопрос, можно ли компилировать только, к примеру, один класс программы. 
Просто проект огромный, и ждать пока скомпилируется на телефон (20 минут) не очень удобно.
Если я поменял одну строку в каком-то классе, могу ли я ускорить процесс? Как-то сообщить IDE, что я сделал изменения только в этом классе и не нужно заново весь проект компилировать?

Comment: надеяться на инкрементальную сборку;) а так вам поможет разбитие на множество модулей. но это рефакторинг на месяц минимум

Comment: к сожалению, я такого способа не знаю. Ява машина хорошо оптимизирована, но даже при этом условии, ей требуется некоторое время на пересорку пакета (даже при наличии кэша).  В общем, это всеравно виртуалка, с этим ничего не поделаешь.

Comment: Сам только изучаю яву и андроид, поэтому не пинайте строго, могу ошибаться. :-) В качестве альтернативы можно попробовать компилировать через bat-файл. Вот есть описание: https://habr.com/post/210584/ Я для себя пробовал такой вариант (правда на простых проектах) разница довольно существенна: в студии это минут 5, через bat-файл секунд 10. Другое дело, что как это связать с самой студией? Видимо, сохраниться, после вручную запустить настроенный на этот проект батник. На выходе apk, который и отправляется на телефон для выполнения.

Comment: instant run же для этого и придуман не?

Answer (score 1):

Оптимизация Gradle это в общем то почти нескончаемая тема

Для начала прочтите мануал, где описаны [способы оптимизации](https://guides.gradle.org/performance/)

Во вторых включите в настройках Gradle (*gradle.properties*) параллелизацию задач:

```
org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Ну и прогоните профайлер (флаг `--profile`), который покажет где у вас узкое место.

Не скидывайте со счетов *Instant Run*:

Таск:  *Deployment > Instant Run* - часто глючит, но для мелких изменений гуд.

Comment: @Daniil Muntyan Еще если работаете на Window's, выключайте из индексации системой и антивирусника исходники своей программы. Т.к. gradle генерирует просто не по мерное количество мелких файлов при полном ребилде, что заметно замедляет сборку.